# Allowed compiler optimizations on loops in C++11

Tags: c++, language-lawyer

Is a C++11-compliant compiler allowed to optimize/transform this code from:

```
bool x = true; // *not* an atomic type, but suppose bool can be read/written atomically
/*...*/
{
    while (x); // spins until another thread changes the value of x
}
```

to anything equivalent to an infinite loop:

```
{
    while (true); // infinite loop
}
```

The above conversion is certainly valid from the point of view of a single-thread program, but this is not the general case.

Also, was that optimization allowed in pre-C++11?

Comment: Is `x` a global variable?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

**Absolutely.**

Since `x` is not marked as `volatile` and appears to be a local object with automatic storage duration and internal linkage, and the program does not modify it, the two programs are equivalent.

In both C++03 and C++11 this is by the as-if rule, since accessing a non-volatile object is *not* considered to be a "side effect" of the program:

> `[C++11: 1.9/12]:` **Accessing an object designated by a volatile glvalue (3.10), modifying an object, calling a library I/O function, or calling a function that does any of those operations are all side effects, which are changes in the state of the execution environment.** Evaluation of an expression (or a sub-expression) in general includes
>   both value computations (including determining the identity of an object for glvalue evaluation and fetching a value previously assigned to an object for prvalue evaluation) and initiation of side effects. When a call to a library I/O function returns or an access to a volatile object is evaluated the side effect is considered complete, even though some external actions implied by the call (such as the I/O itself) or by the volatile access may not have completed yet.

C++11 does make room for a *global* object to have its value changed in one thread then that new value read in another:

> `[C++11: 1.10/3]:` The value of an object visible to a thread `T` at a particular point is the initial value of the object, a value assigned to the object by `T`, **or a value assigned to the object by another thread**, according to the rules below.

However, if you're doing this, since your object is not atomic:

> `[C++11: 1.10/21]:` The execution of a program contains a data race if it contains two conflicting actions in different threads, at least one of which is not atomic, and neither happens before the other. Any such data race results in undefined behavior.

And, when undefined behaviour is invoked, *anything can happen*.

#### Bootnote

> `[C++11: 1.10/25]:` An implementation should ensure that the last value (in modification order) assigned by an atomic or synchronization operation will become visible to all other threads in a finite period of time.

Again, note that the object would have to be *atomic* (say, `std::atomic<bool>`) to obtain this guarantee.

Comment: What if `x` is a global variable?

Comment: If x is a global variable, AND the loop calls functons that MAY alter the global variable, then the compiler is obliged to reload the variable. But in the example above, the loop itself is empty, which means the compiler only has to read the variable once, before the loop, and then use the value it read for the determination of the loop duration.

Comment: @Mats It's not, because the object is not atomic.

Comment: Ok, so if we remove threads from the equation for a second, and we have a global variable `x` in our code, and a `while(x) { foo(); } . The function `foo` is  in a different translation unit, which modifies `x` under some certain condition, as far as I know this works. So while I understand that there is no guarantee from the language perspective, the value will be reloaded. When we add threads it then come down to "when does a changed value in a variable get seen by another thread", which is beyond what `volatile` helps with, since the processor caches may not get synchronised...

Comment: @Mats Question is about C++ and compliance in the loosest case, not the specific behaviours of some specific implementation. However, you're right in that `volatile` does _not_ provide that guarantee; instead, atomicity does.

Comment: I don't disagree that there are potential problems - or that the C++ allows the compiler to start World War three if you do this. But the compiler will generate a reload of a global variable if a function (that it can't determine the effects). Which is what I said... The reload may not actually see the new value, which is a different matter - or are you saying that the compiler will not reload global variables in this case?

Comment: @Mats I'm gonna neither dispute nor agree with that as I don't know what some compiler will do internally. Ultimately, and certainly in the context of this question, it doesn't matter! :) _Especially_ since the OP's code doesn't invoke any such function.

Answer (score 1):

The compiler is allowed go do anything to those two loops. Including terminating the program. Because infinite loops have undefined behaviour if they do not perform a synchronization-like operation (do something that requires synchronization with another thread or I/O), according to the [C++ memory model](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/memory_model):

> Note that it means that a program with endless recursion or endless loop (whether implemented as a for-statement or by looping goto or otherwise) has undefined behavior.