# Why does GCC optimize away this incrementation?

Tags: c++, gcc, optimization

Consider the following code:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <signal.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <stdio.h>

uint64_t counter = 0;

#define __STDC_FORMAT_MACROS
#include <inttypes.h>

void sig_handler(int signo) {
   printf( "%" PRIu64 "\n", counter);

}

int main() {
    struct sigaction act;
    act.sa_handler = &sig_handler;
    sigaction(SIGINT, &act, NULL);

    for( ;; ) {
        counter++;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

If I compile the code with `-O0`, I can see that the counter gets incremented when I press CTR+C. With `-O1`, this is optimized away. Why is that and how could I avoid it?

Comment: Whoops, I forgot to add `volatile`.

Comment: This might be pertinent: http://stackoverflow.com/q/15187459/10077

Comment: Inside a signal handler, you must only access shared variables if their type is `volatile sig_atomic_t` (or one of the `std::atomic` types in C++11).

Comment: For the person who voted to close b/c it is not reproducible, it is indeed you can [see it live here](http://goo.gl/ffykaO).

Comment: It wasn't about not being possible to reproduce but because it was a simple error. I actually agree with that, though it's not "typographical".

Comment: I think it is still an interesting question that will be useful to others, the answer is not likely to be obvious to most. That makes it a great fit for SO.

Comment: Also, since the case for volatile changes in C++14 that is no longer a valid solution

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It looks like the following section of the draft C++11 standard is relevant section `1.9` *[intro.execution]*:

> When the processing of the abstract machine is interrupted by receipt
>   of a signal, the values of objects which are neither
>
> - of type volatile std::sig_atomic_t nor
> - lock-free atomic objects (29.4)
>
> are unspecified during the execution of the signal handler, and the
>   value of any object not in either of these two categories that is
>   modified by the handler becomes undefined.

Since `counter` is nether *volatile* nor an *atomic object* the value is unspecified and therefore the compiler is allowed to optimize it away via the [as-if rule](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/as_if).

The wording changed in C++14 draft and we have the following:

> If a signal handler is executed as a result of a call to the raise function, then the execution of the handler is
>   sequenced after the invocation of the raise function and before its return. [ Note: When a signal is received
>   for another reason, the execution of the signal handler is usually unsequenced with respect to the rest of the
>   program. —end note ]

which seems to leave it unspecified in a sense, since the it is only the note that says the sequence handler is unsequenced, but if we read [N3910: N3910: What can signal handlers do? (CWG 1441)](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2014/n3910.html) we can see that this seems to be considered a data race and thus undefined behavior.

Comment: The wording has changed in C++14. Unfortunately it got more complicated, and I can't understand it anymore.

Comment: @Brian yes, I added a link to the paper that seems to have introduced the new wording it is long but basically it seems like a data race i.e. undefined behavior but I have to read it in more detail.

Answer (score 1):

Your code exhibits undefined behavior, according to the progress guarantee rule in section 1.10:

> The implementation may assume that any thread will eventually do one of the following:
>
> - terminate,
> - make  a  call  to  a  library  I/O  function,
> - access  or  modify  a  volatile  object,  or
> - perform  a  synchronization  operation  or  an  atomic  operation.
>
> [ Note:   This  is  intended  to  allow  compiler  transformations  such  as  removal  of  empty  loops,  even  when termination cannot be proven.  — end note ]

Because your loop does none of these, the optimizer may assume the loop is never entered, and remove it completely.